# When assigning to array, LHS and RHS should have the same number of values

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am assigning a value to an array `dataBase` with the white pixel count of images using the function `count`. The function `count()` is working properly but not the assignment to the `dataBase` array. Please help me with this. The prototypes of functions are,

count(),

```
function whitecount = new(image1)
```

The error am receiving is,

*???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and
 I must be the same.*

Error in ==> init at 9
    dataBase(i)= w;

complete function of init()

```
function dataBase = init();

dataBase=zeros(1,1000);
srcFiles = dir('DB\*.jpg');

for i=1: length(srcFiles)
    filename = strcat('DB\',srcFiles(i).name);
    w = count(filename);
    dataBase(i)= w; 
end
```

Comment: Could you complete your question by quoting the error message matlab gave you and properly defining what are prototypes of init() and count().

Comment: And more important, can you post the output of count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `count` returns something other than a scalar value, the assignment will fail since `dataBase(i)` takes a scalar value only.

You have two options

1. Ensure that `w` is always a non-empty scalar
2. make `dataBase` into a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/matlab_prog/what-is-a-cell-array.html)